# Killing a process with system C++

Tags: c++, process

Is killing a process like `system("taskkill /IM notepad.exe /F")` good? Any other way?

Comment: Assuming windows, there is TerminateProcess API. Killing processes like that is likely to raise a malware flag.

Comment: Forcefully killing a process is never a good idea, but sometimes it is just inevitable. Best avoided. As @MichaelChourdakis said, prefer the API for the task.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to kill, or otherwise interact with processes in C++.

Note that using `std::system` with variable command is dangerous due to potential for shell injection, so be sure to use a constant command.

It is generally better to use a system library call instead of executing another process that does so. The API to use depend on the target system.

POSIX standard for example specifies the function `kill` that can be used to raise a signal to the target process. Raising the SIGETERM signal is a request for the process to terminate gracefully. SIGKILL will cause the operating system to terminate the process unconditionally.